# How to find 4th Saturday of month?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please let me know that how to find fourth Saturday of month in oracle. suppose we put "03/02/1999" then write a sql query to find out fourth saturday of month.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question but it's really badly asked. Please read http://www/stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, revise your question, show what you've already tried and give it a fighting chance!

Comment: What did you try so far? You will find what you are looking for in the date function documentation. What you need something like datepart, month, dateadd and so on. (if you use tsql)

Comment: Investigate the use of the functions Trunc(date) and Next_Day(), and date arithmetic in Oracle. They have everything you need to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle you can use this:

```
NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE('1999-02-03','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'MM')-1, 'Saturday')+3*7
```

Comment: Of course it does not return the 3rd Saturday, it returns exactly what the question asked for.

Comment: Yes, that's what was asked: "write a sql query to find out **fourth** saturday of month"

Answer (score 0):

```
 select next_day(trunc(to_date('1999-02-             03','yyyy-mm-dd'),'mm')-1,'saturday')+21 
 from dual;
```

Comment: `select next_day(trunc(to_date('2014-02-03','yyyy-mm-dd'),'mm'),'saturday')+21 from dual;` gives `March, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000` which is not even in the same month.

Comment: Ans edited.. Forgot to include -1

Answer (score 0):

[`TRUNC( date, [fmt] )`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) takes an optional second argument which determines what time portion you are truncating to; so:

```
TRUNC( your_date, 'mm' )
```

Will truncate to the first day of the month and if you subtract a day from it then you get the last day of the previous month:

```
TRUNC( your_date, 'mm' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

or, more simply,

```
TRUNC( your_date, 'mm' ) - 1
```

[`NEXT_DAY( date, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm) will get the next day, as specified by the second argument, from the given date. Combining the two functions will give you the first specified day of the month:

```
NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( your_date, 'mm' ) - 1, day_of_week )
```

Adding two weeks to it will give you the fourth day-of-the-week of the month:

```
NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( your_date, 'mm' ) - 1, 'Saturday' ) + INTERVAL '21' DAY
```

As an example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eed9/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dates ( your_date ) AS
SELECT TO_DATE( '2014-' || LPAD( LEVEL, 2, '0' ) || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 12
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( your_date, 'mm') - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'Saturday') + INTERVAL '21' DAY AS fourth_saturday
FROM   dates
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eed9/5/0)**:

```
|                  FOURTH_SATURDAY |
|----------------------------------|
|   January, 25 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  February, 22 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|     March, 22 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|     April, 26 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|       May, 24 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|      June, 28 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|      July, 26 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|    August, 23 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
| September, 27 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|   October, 25 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  November, 22 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

You could also wrap the code in a (more generic) function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nth_day_of_month (
  month       DATE,
  day_of_week VARCHAR2,
  nth         NUMBER
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( month, 'mm' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, day_of_week ) + (nth - 1) * 7;
END nth_day_of_month;
/
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( nth_day_of_month( your_date, 'Monday', 1 ), 'DAY YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS first_monday,
       TO_CHAR( nth_day_of_month( your_date, 'Saturday', 4 ), 'DAY YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS fourth_saturday
FROM   dates
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eed9/5/1)**:

```
|      FIRST_MONDAY |     FOURTH_SATURDAY |
|-------------------|---------------------|
| MONDAY 2014-01-06 | SATURDAY 2014-01-25 |
| MONDAY 2014-02-03 | SATURDAY 2014-02-22 |
| MONDAY 2014-03-03 | SATURDAY 2014-03-22 |
| MONDAY 2014-04-07 | SATURDAY 2014-04-26 |
| MONDAY 2014-05-05 | SATURDAY 2014-05-24 |
| MONDAY 2014-06-02 | SATURDAY 2014-06-28 |
| MONDAY 2014-07-07 | SATURDAY 2014-07-26 |
| MONDAY 2014-08-04 | SATURDAY 2014-08-23 |
| MONDAY 2014-09-01 | SATURDAY 2014-09-27 |
| MONDAY 2014-10-06 | SATURDAY 2014-10-25 |
| MONDAY 2014-11-03 | SATURDAY 2014-11-22 |
```

Comment: A lot of text for such a simple question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,0,GETDATE()), 0);
 -- This clause is just to get some numbers: a Tally table, for joining to get a range of dates
WITH NumDays AS ( 
SELECT TOP 365 -- one year of days
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sc1.ID) AS N
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2
UNION SELECT 0 -- just to get a zero in the results
 ), DateRange AS (
SELECT N,
DATEADD(day, N, @StartDate) AS [Date],
DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(day, N, @StartDate)) AS [Day],
DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(day, N, @StartDate)) AS [DayName],
DATENAME(week,DATEADD(day, N, @StartDate)) AS [WeekNo]
FROM NumDays
 )
 SELECT * 
 FROM DateRange
 WHERE [DayName] = 'Saturday'
 AND WeekNo in (4)
```

Here you can give `weekNo` comma separated. Suppose you want find 2nd and 4th Saturday then add this `WeekNo in (2,4)` instead of `WeekNo in (4)`